# How to console.log an object definition and a text in same string?

Tags: javascript, object, concatenation, console.log

I have this JavaScript code:

```
console.log(obj);// [query: "wordOfTheDay"]
console.log(note + " : " + obj ); // obj does not show up
```

I want to make "obj" display in the same string as "note" no matter the type it come in as.

For example:

```
console.log("text sample : " + obj ); // text sample : [query: "wordOfTheDay"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: There's not much point to forcing all logged items into a concatenated string. `console.log` takes as many parms as you want to give it and logs them in the same log line with their types preserved. Just do: `console.log('text sample:', obj);`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[`console.log` accepts any number of parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log), so just send each piece as its own param. That way you keep the formatting of the object in the console, and its all on one entry.

```js
var obj = {
    query:  'wordOfTheDay',
    title:  'Frog',
    url:    '/img/picture.jpg'
};

console.log( "Text Here", obj);

// Text Here Object {query: "wordOfTheDay", title: "Frog", url: "/img/picture.jpg"}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the proper use of `console.log`

Comment: :D It worked!
So I should pass then as different parameters.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you know why Alfonso's answer does not work?
JSON.stringify(obj) returned an empty object as a string "[]".
Will do some research of my own, but if you have some quick pointers, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, what does your object look like? If you just want to debug, then there's not much point to using `JSON.stringify`, because that just gives you a static and boring string, compared to logging it separately.

Comment: @CiprianGheorghite `JSON.stringify` should work as well, it you just want it as a string. It even works with multi-dimensional objects, though it gets harder to read than just logging the object itself. [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/kas2nvzy/2/).

Comment: @PhilippeOceangermanique I've removed the broken jsFiddle link. The `console.log` does work still though; it's part of [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) still. Perhaps you're encountering a different issue?

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
console.log(note, obj);
```

Comment: The former part of this answer is exactly what should be done. Personally, I'd delete the latter.

Comment: But doesn't console.dir give a slightly different format in the console.  I left it there in case someone had a preference on how its formatted in console.    Maybe I'll take it out tho. ..

Comment: I'm referring to the part where you modify the data.

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` can take arbitrary number of arguments so you can put all data you need to log separating it by commas.

```
console.log("text sample : ", obj, JSON.stringify(obj), (typeof obj), (new Date()))
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
console.log(note, " : ", obj );
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I like using string substitutions to output my obj in the middle of a string like this.

```
console.log('from %o to %o', obj1, obj2);
```

You finf all substitution here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#using_string_substitutions

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to add a common prefix to all console.log();

```
let baseLog = console.log;
console.log = function(){
    baseLog("Homepage", ...arguments);
}
console.log("hello world");
console.log(4, 5, 6);
console.log({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```